# Reactjs Homepage.js is working but the contents is not appearing when running the code?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I tried removing everything in the HomePage.js and still nothing would display. I believe the problem lays between either index.html or app.js.

App.js

```
import './App.css'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import HomePage from './components/HomePage'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

[inspect element in homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4vqX.png)

I tried changing everything in homepage.js and homepage.css. Still no luck even tried re typing the import in App.js etc..

Comment: Show your homepage.jsx file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FCNaCA8Y